# Processing recurring and non recurring payments using one token

Tags: paypal

I am trying to process a set of recurring payments and one non-recurring payment in one go, but using the recurring payment option with 0 as the recurring amount kicks up a fuss (saying that the payment amount must be greater than 0), and using CallMarkExpressCheckout generates another token, which then prevents the recurring payments from being processed, due to an invalid token. How can I process the two different types of payment in one go?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain about the functions you're using, but PayPal's API supports this.  You can simply pass an 'INITAMT' in the SetExpressCheckout API call and it will charge the buyer the appropriate amount immediately, as well as return a recurring payment profile ID after calling  the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API call.